# Got mail from Google: Google Mobile Maps Location Reporting Reminder. How to I stop location reporting?

Tags: geolocation, google-latitude

I just got the following mail:

> Google Mobile Maps Location Reporting Reminder To protect your privacy
>   we would like you to know that Google Mobile Maps is running on your
>   mobile device and reporting your location. This is just a privacy
>   reminder - if you did not enable this or want to stop reporting your
>   location, disable location reporting in Google Mobile Maps location
>   settings. Thanks, Google Mobile Maps Team

And I also got a broken link to how to stop that. So my question is, how do I stop that? Searching google wasn't really helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open Google Maps on Android and select Latitude to disable Latitude. :-)

Comment: Thanks, is there a why to check that its really not reporting?

Comment: @Martin No. Either you trust Google that disabled really means disabled or you don't. In that case you should go with an Google free Android version, which also exists. I would be more concerned by the fact that someone has enabled Latitude without your knowledge and approval. That is why Google sends these periodical reminders. BTW: Latitude itself allows fine granulated control about which location is reported to whom.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to use a desktop client, go to [Google Latitude](https://www.google.com/latitude) and hit the gear icon to go into "History settings". There you can disable keeping of your location history. To delete past data, you'll need to go to [History management](https://www.google.com/latitude/b/0/history/manage), where there's an option to "Delete all history". (There's a link from the "History settings" page.)

Note: They say:

> Your history will not be visible publicly or to your Latitude friends.

Answer (score -4):

Disable location Caching on Android- These devices are provided with an opt-in feature for tracking one’s location. This option may or may not enabled and one can decide it when one’s phone is being set up for use. If one wants to disable the tracking then Go to Settings menu>>> location and security>>> uncheck use wireless networks. With this, Google would not be in a position to either collect the information about one’s location or it stores the same in the phone but the app of Maps helps it to grab the info but it cannot be rendered accurate. However if one wants to erase all the previously stored cached locations then rooting of the device must be done(that means one can run more apps like backup,tethering, a flash custom’s ROM etc.,) After installing the free ‘cache location app‘,one can get a view of a map filled with tracked locations, clear them finally by disabling the cache with one tap.